# Change title depending by an event

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where i use a table, and checkboxes in front each row.
My target is next: When i will click on a checkbox instead of `title: "Title to change",` to show  `selections: [..]`, this is a dropdown. 
I tried to use `render: (value, row, index) => {...`, but it does not work.
My question is, how to show the dropdown which contains:

```
Select all data
Invert current page
Select Odd Row
Select Even Row
```

instead of `Title to change`, when i will click on a checkbox?
link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-mvy5j?file=/index.js:1032-1046

Comment: @Utsav Patel, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Where are you rendering the dropdown?
You are only making the data for dropdown?
Where is it in the `return()`?

Comment: @UtsavPatel, my target is next: by default i want to hide the checkbox and dropdown arrow from first row (where is Name Age Address). After clicking on checkbox in front of `Edward King 0`, i want to display the checkbox from the first row, but the dropdown arrow i want to display instead of `Name` from the first row. Please, tel me if it is clear. Thank You.

Comment: It is not clear. The checkbox that you see is rendered through `<Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />`. 
Does this `Table` component supports dropdowns?

Comment: @UtsavPatel, yes, it supports dropdown. Because `rowSelection` is from `Table` api. This table is taken from Ant Design official site.

Comment: @UtsavPatel, this is the source: https://ant.design/components/table/#header Did you find?

Comment: In the Api, there is no such option for dropdown. Checkbox and radio are provided by default.
https://ant.design/components/table/#API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211697/discussion-between-askmen-and-utsav-patel).

Comment: @UtsavPatel, Your opinion is that there is not a solution to display dropdown instead of Name?
when i click on checkbox

Comment: Not an inbuilt one. 
Checkbox and radio are inbuilt in Table.